# Display page only if user registered before a specific date

Tags: date, user-registration

I'd like to know if it's possible to display a page only for users that registered before a specific date.
Example : I want to display a page (or its content) only for users registered before 1st February 2016.

Comment: Do you mean show something different, or have a page that can only be accessed by logged in users that registered before that date?

Comment: Best is only be accessed by logged in users that registered before that date.

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic function to get the current user and compare it with a custom DateTime to see if the user registered earlier or later:

```
function wpse_219284_registered_before( $date_time ) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $registered_before = false;

    if ( $user instanceof WP_User ) {
        $registered = new DateTime( $user->data->user_registered );
        $limit = new DateTime( $date_time );
        return $registered < $limit;
    }

    return $registered_before;
}
```

Be aware that this defaults to false for e.g. unregistered users.

You can e.g. use it in your templates like this:

```
if ( wpse_219284_registeredBefore( '2015-06-25' ) ) {
    the_content();
} else {
    echo "Registered too late to read this. The early bird catches the worm.";
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. `wp_get_current_user()` relies on `global $current_user`, which gets sets inside [`wp_set_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_current_user/), but relies on [`get_currentuserinfo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/), which can return `FALSE` or simply `NULL`. On top of it, it is filterable, so the only reliable way is to check for an `instanceof \WP_User`. Also you might want to set the return value to `FALSE` instead of returning the date as else it might be `TRUE` in any case ;)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the global issue. I don't get the part with returning date though.

Comment: Ah, sorry. That was me messing up `$date_time` and `$registered_before`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My database prefix is different that wp. Must i change something in the code ?